# NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, char, словари

У меня есть класс, который хранит в себе поле массив размерностью в 2 два элемента, типа `Dictionary<char, char>`. В конструкторе я инициализирую данный массив, вставляя при этом в него элементы. Но выводится "NullReferenceException". В чем проблема? Вот код:

```
public class EncLogic
{
    Dictionary<char, char>[] DefoltLogic;

    public EncLogic()
    {
        DefoltLogic = new Dictionary<char, char>[2];
        for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++)
        {
            char symbol = (char)(i + 1);
            DefoltLogic[0].Add((char)i, symbol);
        }

        for (int i = 97; i <= 122; i++)
        {
            char symbol = (char)(i + 1);
            DefoltLogic[1].Add((char)i, symbol);
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы создаете массив из двух словарей, но нигде не создаете сами словари.
Попробуйте так:

```
DefoltLogic = { new Dictionary<char, char>(), new Dictionary<char, char>() };
```